# Null pointer exception in Java Program

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

> Question: you have to check for n test cases that multiplication of a
>   and b is equal to 3rd input value or not.If equal then print YES
>   otherwise NO.
>        Input: 2 5 6 30 4 3 20
>
> Output: YES NO
>
> Explanation: 2 is number of test cases. 5 is a & 6 is b
>   ,multiplication is 30 so YES
>
> Constraints :
>
> 0 < test cases <= 1000000000 0 < a < b <= 10000000

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;


class ques1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        BigInteger test=new BigInteger(sc.next());

        while(!test.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        {
            Scanner s=new Scanner(br.readLine());
            s.useDelimiter(" ");
            BigInteger p=new BigInteger(s.next());
            BigInteger q=new BigInteger(s.next());
            BigInteger r=new BigInteger(s.next());
            if(p.multiply(q).equals(r))
            {
                System.out.println("YES");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("NO");
            }
            test=test.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
    }
}
```

This program is working fine in eclipse.But while running on online compilers like ideone.com,etc it is giving error message as following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:702)
    at ques1.main(Main.java:18)
```

Constraints are so big so i am using biginteger.I had also used stringtokenizer instead of scanner of input separation,but it is also giving same error.
i have to take input in a spacing format so i am using stringtokenizer or scanner.
Is there is any other way to separate them.

Comment: `br.readLine()` is throwing the NPE, is there a line for it to read..?

Comment: yea, you should check `br.readLine()==null`, *before* `new Scanner()`.

Answer (score 1):

`br.readLine()` will return `null` when reaching the end of the file. And `new Scanner(String)` won't accept `null` as parameter. Apart from that you should always check for valid input / if you can read data from a resource.